# Update or refresh Listview in Windows Phone 8.1 app with C# and XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-phone-8

I need to refresh a `ListView` when the `ItemsSource` are updated. I've declared the `myListView` as a `ListView` within the XAML file and assigned the `myList` as the itemssource in the C# code with following code snippet:

```
myListView.ItemsSource = myList;
```

Now, my question is, how can I refresh `myListView`?

Comment: You should use MVVM.  Makes this stuff trivial.  Go learn it.

Answer (score 4):

What do you mean by refreshing ? If you want your UI to be refreshed , your myList must be ObservableCollection type and your class must implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Check out this post

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You need to use and ObservableCollection

```
public ObservableCollection<string> MyList { get; set; }
```

After setting the observable collection as your ItemsSource every change to the collection will automatically be reflected on your listview.

Answer (score 0):

Great to see that it works only by the use of `System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`, then set the collection in the `ListView.ItemsSource`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  if (ListView.Items.Count > 0)
  {
     ListView.ItemsSource = null;
  }
  listItem.Clear();
```

Just assigning the new list view objects does not clear the data.
You need to clear the ItemSource and also clear the list array used to bind the list view

Answer (score 0):

i'd created a test app - krayknot to test this scenario and here is the code:

Include INotifyPropertyChanged

```
public sealed partial class PivotPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
```

create eventhandler

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

Create ObservableCollection

```
ObservableCollection<Feeds> oc = new ObservableCollection<Feeds>();
```

and here is the method,

```
private async void BindFeeds(string URL)
        {
            progressRing.IsActive = true;

            var uri = new Uri(URL);
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();

            // Always catch network exceptions for async methods
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            var result = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);

            var xmlStream = await result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            XDocument loadedData = XDocument.Load(xmlStream);

            foreach (var data in loadedData.Descendants("Table"))
            {


                try
                {
                    oc.Add(new Feeds
                    {
                        BlogId = data.Element("Blogs_CID").Value.ToString(),
                        Description = data.Element("Blogs_BriefDescription").Value.ToString(),
                        IconImage = videoIcon,
                        Heading = data.Element("Blogs_Heading").Value.ToString().Trim(),
                        MainImage = feedImageThumbnail, //data.Element("Blogs_SquareImagePath").Value.ToString(),
                        TimeStamp = data.Element("TimeElapsed").Value.ToString(),
                        SourceURL = data.Element("Blogs_SourceURL").Value.ToString()
                    });

                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    //throw;
                }               
            }
            httpClient.Dispose();

            if (lstLatest.Items.Count == 0)
            {
                lstLatest.ItemsSource = oc;
            }
            else
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }

            httpClient.Dispose();
            progressRing.IsActive = false;
        }
```